# Node Getting Error: read ECONNRESET when subscribing to many events (some of them successfully subscribes)

Tags: node.js, server, raspberry-pi, publish-subscribe, econnreset

First of all, I´m quite new in programming, and absolutely new in NODE, so maybe my code is not well organized.

I´m using a RaspberryPi to subscribe to 9 events. The following code worked with just 2 events. I gradually added more subscriptions. While the subscriptions are 7 or less, everything is fine. If I try with more, i get ECONNRESET error.

For example, i I try to subscribe to 8 events, I successfully subscribe to 6 and I get the error on 2 of them.

CODE:

```
var http = require('http');
var SPI = require('pi-spi');

var dotstar = require('dotstar');
var sleep = require('sleep');



spi = SPI.initialize('/dev/spidev0.0');

const ledStripLength = 250;

const ledStrip = new dotstar.Dotstar(spi, {
  length: ledStripLength
});






//1. Defining message for subscription
var E1 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/valuechange1/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
var E2 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/valuechange2/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var E3 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/Z1_Changed/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
var E4 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/Z2_Changed/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var E5 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/Z3_Changed/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
var E6 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/Z4_Changed/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var E7 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/Z5_Changed/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var E8 = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {"destUrl":"http://192.168.100.200:3000"}, // Javascript object payload
    json: true,
    url: "http://192.168.1.91/rest/events/PenChangeEnded/notifs", //<-- event we subscribe to.
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

//2. Sending subscriptions.
request(E1, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E1');
});
request(E2, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E2');
});

request(E3, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E3');
});
request(E4, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E4');
});
request(E5, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E5');
});
request(E6, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E6');
});
request(E7, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E7');
});
request(E8, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        return;
    }sleep.msleep(500);
    console.log(' Body :', JSON.stringify(body)); // Just printing the return message as we subscribe.
console.log('subscribed to E9');
});


//3. Just a simple server waiting for the events.
var subServer = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    var method = req.method; //GET / POST / DELETE / OPTIONS ...
    //var body = req.body;
    if(method == 'POST'){

        var body = []; //Payload of the message;
        req.on('data', function(chunk){

            body.push(chunk);
            var body2 = JSON.parse(body);
           console.log("Event received:", body.toString()); //Here we have the body to analyze.

           console.log("Event received:", body2.id);
           if(body2.id=="valuechange1"){
            ledStrip.all(255, 255, 255, 1);
            ledStrip.sync();
           }
           if(body2.id=="DrawStartExecution"){
           ledStrip.all(255, 255, 0, 1);
            ledStrip.sync();
           }






      });
    }
    //responding for incoming event

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end();
}
);



//4. Starting the server on specified port.


subServer.listen(3000, "192.168.100.200", () => {
    console.log("Server started");

});
```

Then, all subscriptions work but E1 and E8 ones. this is what i get in the console :

```
Server started
Error : { Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
Error : { Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:5d18b8d3-44da-47f6-6ed5-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E2
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:925c66f4-8433-4be4-620c-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E3
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:db25d7f0-c8ad-4f1f-666d-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E4
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:19e5a4d2-0170-4399-6a0e-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E5
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:5ac590b7-4dc5-4748-6ee1-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E6
 Body : {"id":"urn:uuid:9f00acd1-8dfb-4b3f-621d-0050c2899089"}
subscribed to E7
```